# Process to restore /bin timeshift backup on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: backup, rsync, restore, binary

I have separate partition for root, home, and swap on the same disk.

I accidentally deleted /bin won't get into that here.

I have a backup via timeshift. But can't boot into the system. Not sure how to restore the timeshift backup of /bin only here are my options I'm thinking of doing:

Couple questions:

1. Boot into live ubuntu 18.04 environment, open a terminal. As root, copy the /bin backup to my root system of my system's disk.
2. From live environment, should I use rsync to move it back? Something like:

   ```
   sudo rsync -a /directory/to/timeshiftbackup /(rootofsystemdisk)
   ```
3. From live environment, install Timeshift, restore it via timeshift restore?

I have some other questions too:

A. What permissions should /bin have on it? So I can double check to make sure Timeshift didn't alter it somehow

B. In Timeshift, is there some way to ONLY restore /bin and not the entire / partition? Here is a screenshot I took of my timeshift restore options a while ago when I was looking at how it worked **https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTn2q.png**

Comment: I see `lrwxrwxrwx` for links and `-rwxr-xr-x` for normal binaries and ownership of `root root`

Comment: Interesting. So /bin is a symbolic link? You ARE on Ubuntu 18.04? I thought that it only became a symbolic link for /usr/bin with 19.XX+ ?

Comment: I never said so I meant the contents of the `/bin` folder

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks y

Answer (score 1):

I just installed Timeshift in a live environment and restored it. NOTE: I have /home and / on separate partitions. I have timeshift set to backup both of those in their entirety. Timeshift does not, afaik, allow you to select only part of the snapshot to backup. Which to me, defeats the purpose of having a separate home part. I'll be looking for a new backup solution.